# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library, Library not loaded: libicui18n.52.dylib

Tags: php, yii2

I use Yii2 Framework.
With clean Yii2 Framework, it sometimes show this error at the bottom of the page

```
    PHP Core Warning 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/intl.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/intl.so, 9): Library not loaded: libicui18n.52.dylib
    Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/intl.so
    Reason: image not found' 

    in Unknown:0

    Stack trace:
    #0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()
    #1 {main}
```

It's NOT ALWAYS appear, if i hit refresh, sometimes it disappear.

I have no idea what i should do, please kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out that reinstall intl via pecl solve my problem.

I have no idea why,...

reference: http://darraghenright.tumblr.com/post/22027208929/installing-intl-package-on-osx-lion